# Spring Security LDAP Authentication throws NO_ATTRIBUTE_OR_VAL error

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

I can't authenticate against a real LDAP/AD when following spring.io guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/

The problem I get when autentication agains a *real* AD/LADP is:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: [LDAP: error code 16 - 00002080: AtrErr: DSID-03080155, #1:
    0: 00002080: DSID-03080155, problem 1001 (NO_ATTRIBUTE_OR_VAL), data 0, Att 23 (userPassword)
]; nested exception is javax.naming.directory.NoSuchAttributeException: [LDAP: error code 16 - 00002080: AtrErr: DSID-03080155, #1:
0: 00002080: DSID-03080155, problem 1001 (NO_ATTRIBUTE_OR_VAL), data 0, Att 23 (userPassword)
]; remaining name 'CN=olahell,OU=Consultants,OU=Production,OU=Company'
```

Below is my java auth config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchFilter("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))")
                .contextSource()
                .url("ldap://company-dc02.company.local:389/dc=company,dc=local")
                .managerDn("CN=olahell,OU=Consultants,OU=Production,OU=Company,DC=company,DC=local")
                .managerPassword("myPassword")
            .and()
                .passwordCompare()
                .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I needed to do was to use `BindAuthenticator`, LDAP should be configured as below:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider() throws Exception {
        String ldapServerUrl = "ldap://company-dc02.bergsala.local:389/dc=company,dc=local";
        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(ldapServerUrl);
        String ldapManagerDn = "CN=olahell,OU=Consultants,OU=Production,OU=Company,DC=company,DC=local";
        contextSource.setUserDn(ldapManagerDn);
        String ldapManagerPassword = "myPassword";
        contextSource.setPassword(ldapManagerPassword);
        contextSource.setReferral("follow");
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        LdapUserSearch ldapUserSearch = new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch("", "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))", contextSource);
        BindAuthenticator bindAuthenticator = new BindAuthenticator(contextSource);
        bindAuthenticator.setUserSearch(ldapUserSearch);
        LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(bindAuthenticator, new EmsLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(contextSource, ""));
        return ldapAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider());
    }
```

NOTE: `EmsLdapAuthoritiesPopulator` extends `DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator` and overrrides `#getAdditionalRoles` to enable me to set extra roles to user.